# Git file-level merge conflict caused by Git “suggesting [the file] should perhaps be moved”

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I've got a Git repo of Markdown articles, where people create pull requests (one per Markdown article) that eventually get merged to `master` and then, working directly on `master`, I move that article into a folder called *wordpressed* and commit and push to `master`.

And I've got a very old pull request that is still sitting there in a branch called `home-base`, consisting of a file *dan/homebase.md* which I'm thinking of editing into shape with some more commits and then merging to `master`.

This `home-base` branch is *so* old that the repo, seen from its point of view, is totally different from how it looks today in `master`. So I thought it might be good to reverse merge `master` into `home-base` just to bring it more up to date and move the merge base up a lot.

But when I try to do that, I get a merge conflict that I can't understand.

---

To show you the situation, I'm going to show what a `ls` of files and folders looks like in each branch. I'll start with `master`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ ls -1 -R
README.md
dan
instructions.md
wordpressed

./dan:

./wordpressed:
AppDelegateRefactor.md
BareListContentView.md
CellContentConfiguration.md
ControlTargetActioniOS14.md
GetStartedWithPods.md
MultipleTrailingClosures.md
StatesAndBackgrounds.md
Swift52notes1.md
Swift52notes2.md
Swift52notes3.md
UserInteractiveCells.md
bdd-common-pitfalls.md
bdd.md
brantsMenuBar.md
collectionViewContentConfig.md
collectionViewLists.md
collectionViewLists2.md
collectionViewOutline.md
debuggingLinks.md
diffableDataSources.md
diffableDataSources2.md
forwardCompatibity.md
haptics.md
iOS13deprecations.md
images
inAppPurchases.md
logging.md
miscSwiftTricks1.md
miscSwiftTricks2.md
miscSwiftTricks3.md
miscSwiftTricks4.md
multipleSelection.md
mysteriesOfLayout.md
newInIOS14.md
packages.md
photoPicker.md
protocolParadox.md
splitViewControllers.md
splitViewControllers2.md
swiftTrickTwoClasses.md
targetActionRant.md
typescript-shape-of-things.md
untappableButton.md
what-vs-how.md
xcode12Editing.md
xcode12testing.md
xcodeWhereAmI.md
xcodeWorkInTwoPlaces.md

./wordpressed/images:
argumentsInScheme.png
bigFlags.png
callHierarchy.png
callersMenu.png
chooser.png
config.png
createdTester.png
dataOrUrl.png
ipadportraitoverlay.png
listOfPepBoys.png
listWithSectionHeaders.png
littleFlags.png
looksLikeADuck.png
newTester.png
outlineIndicatorsWrong.png
outlineIndicatorsWrong2.png
perfectAfterHack.png
pickAPeppa.png
rootOnly.png
sandboxAccountOnDevice.png
selfSizingStringDrawer.png
simpleList.png
split1.png
split2.png
splitViewControllerPadLandscape.png
tableViewAsChoice.png
threecolumns.png
twoPossibilities.png
twoscreensphone.png
variableRowHeights.png
workingOutline.png
```

As you can see, the main folder is itself mostly empty. All the articles are in *wordpressed*, along with their images which are in *wordpressed/images*.

---

Okay, now here is `home-base`:

```
$ git switch home-base
Switched to branch 'home-base'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/home-base'.

$ ls -1 -R
GetStartedWithPods.md
README.md
Swift52notes1.md
Swift52notes2.md
Swift52notes3.md
dan
debuggingLinks.md
images
logging.md
miscSwiftTricks1.md
miscSwiftTricks2.md
miscSwiftTricks3.md
miscSwiftTricks4.md
packages.md
wordpressed
xcode12Editing.md
xcode12testing.md
xcodeWhereAmI.md
xcodeWorkInTwoPlaces.md

./dan:
bdd.md
homebase.md

./images:
chooser.png
config.png
split1.png
split2.png

./wordpressed:
images

./wordpressed/images:
```

As you can see, that's a much earlier situation. Nothing had been moved to *wordpressed* yet. There were a few articles floating around the top level, and the *dan* folder had two articles, including the one I'm interested in here, *homebase.md*.

---

Finally, for the sake of completeness, I'm going to show you the merge base between `master` and `home-base`:

```
$ git merge-base master home-base
b5d7355fe42eddad96beb200df2cba65381c288a
$ git checkout b5d7355fe
$ ls -1 -R
GetStartedWithPods.md
README.md
Swift52notes1.md
Swift52notes2.md
Swift52notes3.md
dan
debuggingLinks.md
images
logging.md
miscSwiftTricks1.md
miscSwiftTricks2.md
miscSwiftTricks3.md
miscSwiftTricks4.md
packages.md
wordpressed
xcode12Editing.md
xcode12testing.md
xcodeWhereAmI.md
xcodeWorkInTwoPlaces.md

./dan:
bdd.md

./images:
chooser.png
config.png
split1.png
split2.png

./wordpressed:
images

./wordpressed/images:
```

Well, it looks an awful lot like `home-base` looks now, doesn't it? The main difference is that that's before *homebase.md* appeared in the *dan* folder.

---

Now then. Ask yourself, please, what should happen when I try to merge `master` into `home-base`. What are contributions from both sides of the merge? In my view, Git should realize that in `master` a lot of new files appeared in *wordpressed*, and that some of them are renames of files that used to be at the top level. Plus, of course, in `home-base`, a new file *homebase.md* has appeared in *dan*.

Those contributions should not conflict (in my view).

Okay, let's try it.

```
$ git switch home-base
$ git merge master
CONFLICT (file location): dan/homebase.md added in HEAD inside a directory that was renamed in master, suggesting it should perhaps be moved to wordpressed/homebase.md.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git status
On branch home-base
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/home-base'.

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
    deleted:    dan/homebase.md
    new file:   instructions.md
    new file:   wordpressed/AppDelegateRefactor.md
    new file:   wordpressed/BareListContentView.md
    new file:   wordpressed/CellContentConfiguration.md
    new file:   wordpressed/ControlTargetActioniOS14.md
    renamed:    GetStartedWithPods.md -> wordpressed/GetStartedWithPods.md
    new file:   wordpressed/MultipleTrailingClosures.md
    new file:   wordpressed/StatesAndBackgrounds.md
    renamed:    Swift52notes1.md -> wordpressed/Swift52notes1.md
    renamed:    Swift52notes2.md -> wordpressed/Swift52notes2.md
    renamed:    Swift52notes3.md -> wordpressed/Swift52notes3.md
    new file:   wordpressed/UserInteractiveCells.md
    new file:   wordpressed/bdd-common-pitfalls.md
    renamed:    dan/bdd.md -> wordpressed/bdd.md
    new file:   wordpressed/brantsMenuBar.md
    new file:   wordpressed/collectionViewContentConfig.md
    new file:   wordpressed/collectionViewLists.md
    new file:   wordpressed/collectionViewLists2.md
    new file:   wordpressed/collectionViewOutline.md
    renamed:    debuggingLinks.md -> wordpressed/debuggingLinks.md
    new file:   wordpressed/diffableDataSources.md
    new file:   wordpressed/diffableDataSources2.md
    new file:   wordpressed/forwardCompatibity.md
    new file:   wordpressed/haptics.md
    new file:   wordpressed/iOS13deprecations.md
    new file:   wordpressed/images/argumentsInScheme.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/bigFlags.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/callHierarchy.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/callersMenu.png
    renamed:    images/chooser.png -> wordpressed/images/chooser.png
    renamed:    images/config.png -> wordpressed/images/config.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/createdTester.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/dataOrUrl.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/ipadportraitoverlay.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/listOfPepBoys.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/listWithSectionHeaders.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/littleFlags.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/looksLikeADuck.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/newTester.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/outlineIndicatorsWrong.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/outlineIndicatorsWrong2.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/perfectAfterHack.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/pickAPeppa.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/rootOnly.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/sandboxAccountOnDevice.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/selfSizingStringDrawer.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/simpleList.png
    renamed:    images/split1.png -> wordpressed/images/split1.png
    renamed:    images/split2.png -> wordpressed/images/split2.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/splitViewControllerPadLandscape.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/tableViewAsChoice.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/threecolumns.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/twoPossibilities.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/twoscreensphone.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/variableRowHeights.png
    new file:   wordpressed/images/workingOutline.png
    new file:   wordpressed/inAppPurchases.md
    renamed:    logging.md -> wordpressed/logging.md
    renamed:    miscSwiftTricks1.md -> wordpressed/miscSwiftTricks1.md
    renamed:    miscSwiftTricks2.md -> wordpressed/miscSwiftTricks2.md
    renamed:    miscSwiftTricks3.md -> wordpressed/miscSwiftTricks3.md
    renamed:    miscSwiftTricks4.md -> wordpressed/miscSwiftTricks4.md
    new file:   wordpressed/multipleSelection.md
    new file:   wordpressed/mysteriesOfLayout.md
    new file:   wordpressed/newInIOS14.md
    renamed:    packages.md -> wordpressed/packages.md
    new file:   wordpressed/photoPicker.md
    new file:   wordpressed/protocolParadox.md
    new file:   wordpressed/splitViewControllers.md
    new file:   wordpressed/splitViewControllers2.md
    new file:   wordpressed/swiftTrickTwoClasses.md
    new file:   wordpressed/targetActionRant.md
    new file:   wordpressed/typescript-shape-of-things.md
    new file:   wordpressed/untappableButton.md
    new file:   wordpressed/what-vs-how.md
    renamed:    xcode12Editing.md -> wordpressed/xcode12Editing.md
    renamed:    xcode12testing.md -> wordpressed/xcode12testing.md
    renamed:    xcodeWhereAmI.md -> wordpressed/xcodeWhereAmI.md
    renamed:    xcodeWorkInTwoPlaces.md -> wordpressed/xcodeWorkInTwoPlaces.md

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    added by us:     wordpressed/homebase.md
```

---

Okay, so that last line is the one I don't understand. What does it mean to say that "added by us" is *wordpressed/homebase.md*? *NO!* That's not where we added it. We added it in *dan*.

Neither `master` nor `home-base` has a file *wordpressed/homebase.md*. So where is Git getting the idea that there is one??? It seems to have something to do with the same reason why it thinks there is a merge conflict at all:

> *dan/homebase.md* added in HEAD inside a directory that was renamed in master, suggesting it should perhaps be moved to wordpressed/homebase.md.

So: *What is Git talking about here?* Why does Git think that *dan/homebase.md* should be *wordpressed/homebase.md*, on no evidence whatever that I can find? How can I prevent this merge conflict and get Git to be more simplistic about this? Could I perhaps use a different merge strategy? Or how can I simply resolve the conflict in such a way as to say, No, Git, just leave *dan/homebase.md* alone, please?

Again, apologies for the length of the detail in the question.

Comment: Conflicts are conflicts, and you could still get the same result from a different type of merge or even from a rebase.  Best practice is to not let your various branches get so out of sync that you have this problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Interesting idea, but it isn't my fault that things went on like this so long. The author of the _homebase.md_ article sort of abandoned it. Now I want to recover it. Besides, getting "out of sync" is what branches _do_. That is why branches exist — so that they can branch.

Comment: Branches do not exist to get out of sync. People should be merging master into home-base frequently. Weekly, if not daily. That is what @TimBiegeleisen is talking about.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I would argue the contrary. Branches should be merged *when they are ready* and not before that. Merging branches while they are in random states just introduces another element of instability. If you absolutely have to merge a main branch back into a feature branch, then you should do that when the main branch is in a well-known stable state. That at least is the common wisdom among the inventors of Git.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This particular conflict:

> ```
> CONFLICT (file location): dan/homebase.md added in HEAD inside a
> directory that was renamed in master, suggesting it should perhaps
> be moved to wordpressed/homebase.md.
> ```

is a relatively modern invention in Git.  Git now tries to find *directory renames* between the merge base commit and each tip commit.  That is, having run `git diff --find-renames <base> <left>` and `git diff --find-renames <base> <right>`, it detected some number of renames on the left and some number of renames on the right (with the total number being positive).  At least some of those renames implied a directory-name change.  So Git now thinks that maybe the *other* side of the merge should have the same directory-name-changes applied.

(Git pre-release versions in the mid 2.teens or so had various experimental versions of this code added and I forget when it really stabilized.  Perusing the release notes, it looks like 2.17 is when it went in, and then there was a subsequent corner case fixed in 2.19.)

[Edit, 15 Apr 2021:] When this new feature went in, so did a new control knob: `merge.directoryRenames`.  Its default value is `conflict`, but you can set it to `true` (meaning always make the assumption it is already making, but don't call it a conflict) or `false` (meaning never make the new assumption, and thus don't call it a conflict).

This is the only conflict that Git is announcing, so it's the only file that shows up in the final "unmerged files" section:

> ```
> Unmerged paths:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
>     added by us:     wordpressed/homebase.md
> ```

Git has, here, taken its own internal suggestion: it believes that everything added to `dan/` between the merge base and `HEAD` should have been added instead to `wordpressed/` due to changes it saw between the merge base and the tip of `master`.

If this seems correct to you, Git would like you to confirm this, by running `git add` on that path name.  If not, Git would like you to move the file to wherever you think it should go, and `git add` the result (and remove, with `git rm` or perhaps with `git add`, the name Git used).

Comment: I don't quite know where Git picks up the directory rename idea from. It would be interesting to run `git diff --find-renames` from merge base to master to see if there's anything identifiable there. As for the later merge, that should now have a different merge base, which one would hope reduces this sort of thing.

Comment: Okay, the vast preponderance is entirely new stuff in _wordpressed_ or stuff that was moved (renamed) from top level to _wordpressed_. There is exactly _one_ existing rename where an article was moved from _dan_ to _wordpressed_: `diff --git a/dan/bdd.md b/wordpressed/bdd.md`. And yet on just that basis alone, Git assumes that this new article that popped up in _dan_ should have popped up in _wordpressed_ instead?? I'm sorry, I regard this as a Git bug. There needs at the very least to be a way to turn off this "feature", surely.

Comment: Generalizing from "one" to "all" does seem just a teensy bit aggressive, to say the least. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy to report a bug to the Git people.

Comment: By the way my actual solution was `mv` plus `git rm --cached` and then commit.

Comment: Just for the sake of concluding this thread: I did write in to the Git mailing list and got a very helpful answer. Yes, Git is basing its strategy on the fact that 100% of files in _dan_ — all one of them, as my respondent delightfully put it — got moved. And, more important, we can turn off this behavior by setting `git config` option `merge.directoryRenames` to `false`. Of course I would then probably turn it back on again. There is, I believe, no corresponding merge strategy option for a single merge action, so you have to play with `git config` instead.

Comment: I saw that on the mailing list. I had missed these new `merge.directoryRenames` settings (they're very easy to miss!). I'll edit this answer to mention them.

Comment: This is a long discussion, but it does not explicitly say what I ought to type to make this happen.  Especially if I disagree with Git's proposed relocation of the file, I don't see what to do.