# File location conflicts during git merge

Tags: git, merge, file-rename

In git, I merged another branch and received some file location conflicts:

```
git merge other_branch
[..]
CONFLICT (file location): localPath/SomeFile.cs added in HEAD inside a directory
that was renamed in other_branch, suggesting it should perhaps be moved
to path_in_other_branch/SomeFile.cs.
```

When I am later prompted to resolve the conflict it looks like this:

```
Deleted merge conflict for 'path_in_other_branch/SomeFile.cs':
  {local}: created file
  {remote}: deleted
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort?
```

So it seems like git has already followed its suggestion to move the file. I don't want it to, but that is not an option: If I choose 'c', I keep the file in the new, undesired directory. If I choose 'd', the file is deleted.

I can work around this if I choose option 'd' and then revert the file change.

But surely there has to be a better way? How can I tell git to not move the file / manually resolve the file location conflict?

Comment: It appears that `git mergetool` was never updated to allow the option of using the original pathname. You can do this *outside* `git mergetool` though.

Comment: Sounds like what I encountered: [Git file-level merge conflict caused by Git “suggesting \[the file\] should perhaps be moved”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067686/git-file-level-merge-conflict-caused-by-git-suggesting-the-file-should-perhap)