# Git fix wrong rename mapping

Tags: git

I have a project with `branch-1` and `branch-2` 
In `branch-1` I copy a file to make another use of it:
Before

```
root/
    code.cpp
```

After

```
root/
    src/
       code.cpp
    test/
       code.cpp
```

Accidentally, when merge to master (which I have not permission to change), git recognize as `rename {root/ => root/test/}code.cpp`. 
Now every time I change code is `code.cpp` in `branch-2` and cherry-pick to `branch-1`, all changes will be apply to `test/code.cpp` instead of `src/code.cpp`

How do I correct this?

Comment: Have you already thought about doing `git mv root/test/code.cpp root/src/code.cpp`?

Comment: @MikeKim yes, but it is seem to work if  the commit has not been done. Now the commit is merge, I can not revert it for some reason, and I'm finding the way to fix it

Comment: Reminds me of my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067686/git-file-level-merge-conflict-caused-by-git-suggesting-the-file-should-perhap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an addition for @torek answer

For @torek answer, using `git merge-file` require 3 files, and he did not mention how to get these 3 files

`git merge-file <target> <base> <changed>`
As git-merge-file documented, `git-merge-file` will get the change from `<base>` to `<changed>` onto `<target>`

For this scenario: `<target>` will be `src/code.cpp`, `<changed>` will be `code.cpp` (with `-X no-rename` the file `code.cpp` will be mark as `deleted by us`), but we do not have `<base>` file.

To solve this, I add to `.gitconfig` following:

```
[mergetool "manual"]
    cmd = echo "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

Then I run `git merge-tool --tool=manual code.cpp`. When the tool asked if the merge successful or not I Ctrl-C to interrupt it. Now I was left with 4 files, "*_BACKUP_*" "*_BASE_*" "*_LOCAL_*" "*_REMOTE_*". And `<base>` will be "*_BASE_*"

Now I can run `git-merge-file` normally.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to *combine work* in the files after the fact, consider `git merge-file` (see below).  But the answer to "how do I fix this" is:  You don't.  Git doesn't actually have file renaming in the first place, so there's nothing to fix!

Now, you might object that, hey, Git itself is saying "rename" here.  And it is.  But it's not because the file *was* renamed.  It's because Git is testing—at the time you ask it to tell you about the two commits—to see if it can *pretend* the file was renamed.  If Git thinks that saying "rename this file" produces *shorter and clearer output*, Git will *say* that.

You can *turn this off* with the `--no-renames` option:

```
git diff --no-renames <commit-hash-ID-1> <commit-hash-ID-2>
```

Now when Git compares two commits, it won't ever say "rename".  Instead, it will say "delete file" and "add file".

> when [I] merge

For `git merge`, use `-X no-renames` instead of `--no-renames`.  (Why this is a different option spelling than `git diff`'s `--no-renames` is mostly historical, and the usual bad user-experience design of Git.)

> and cherry-pick

The cherry-pick code uses Git's merge engine, so here again, use `-X no-renames` to make Git stop calling that a "rename".

## Long: all the raw details

We'll start with an overview of `git merge`, since all this stuff uses Git's merge engine.

#### Git's automatic method for combining work

When you run `git merge other`, Git does the following:

- locate the *current* commit (via `HEAD`);
- locate the commit specified by `other`: this can be a branch name or a raw commit hash ID, or anything acceptable to `git rev-parse` really; and
- using those two commits, locate a third commit, the *merge base*.

To illustrate this with a regular (and real<sup>1</sup>) merge, let's consider the following graph fragment:

```
          o--...--L   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--B
         \
          o--...--R   <-- br2
```

That is, you're currently "on" branch `br1`, using commit `L` (`L` here stands in for a big ugly hash ID, which we'll call `LOCAL` as `git mergetool` does, or `--ours` as `git restore` does).  You ask Git to merge in commit `R` via `git merge br2`.  Git uses the history—the parent linkage from commits to earlier commits—to find a third commit, which I call `B` here.  This is the *merge base*.  It is the "best common (shared) commit", or technically, the output from running a [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) algorithm.<sup>2</sup>

Git now, in effect, runs:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-L>
```

to see what "we" changed on "our" branch `br1`.  Using `-X no-renames` makes Git leave out the `--find-renames` part.

Git then runs a second `git diff` command:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-B> <hash-of-R>
```

to see what "they" changed on "their" branch `br2`, since the same starting point (commit `B`).  Again, using `-X no-renames` disables the `--find-renames` step.

*With* the `--find-renames` step, Git will sometimes pair up some file that *was* in `B` and is deleted in `L` and/or `R` with some file that *wasn't* in `B` but is newly-created in `L` and/or `R`.  Git will call this a *rename* and will attempt to preserve this rename change.  *Without* the `--find-renames` step, Git will not do this pairing-up, which avoids the problem that occurs if Git finds the *wrong* pair, but now leaves you with "file was deleted".

In all cases—with or without `--find-renames`—Git now has a bunch of possibilities:

- the file exists and has the same name in all three commits (`B`, `L`, and `R`);
- a file was renamed and/or deleted in the `B`-to-`L` and/or `B`-to-`R` transition;
- a file was created from scratch in one or both of the `B`-to-`L` and/or `B`-to-`R` transitions.

The first case is the easiest and most common one, which Git usually handles pretty well on its own.  The second and third cases can cause Git to stop with a *merge conflict* if it does not know how to combine the `B`-to-`L` and `B`-to-`R` changes.

In cases where three version of the file *do* exist (renames included), we now have "three versions" of "the same file" (even if the file has different file names in `L` and/or `R`).  Git now tries to combine any *content* changes made in the `B`-to-`L` and/or `B`-to-`R` diffs.  If one side touched the contents and the other side did not, Git will take the changes from the side that did touch the contents.  If neither side touched the contents, Git will take any of the three versions of the file.  **If both sides touched the contents, Git uses `git merge-file` on the three input files to attempt to combine the changes.**

The result of `git merge-file` can either be "successful merge" or "merge conflict detected".  If a merge conflict is detected, Git:

- writes its best approximation of merging to the *working tree*, and
- leaves the three input files in its *index*, using nonzero staging numbers.

Using `git ls-files --stage --unmerged`, you can see the three versions of the file in Git's index; you can use `git checkout-index` or similar (including `git mergetool`) to get the three versions.

When a file is (or is detected as) deleted, though, there is at least one version that is *not* in the index.  You may still be able to recover the merge base version of the file from the index, which is particularly handy for merges, since identifying commit `B` can be tricky.  See [the `git checkout-index` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index) for details here.

**If the file wasn't actually deleted, but was instead renamed—Git just mis-identified the correct new file—and/or has work that needs to be combined, you now have to bypass Git's normal automation.**

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git merge` command will sometimes use short-cuts, when a real merge is not required.  We won't cover that case here since it doesn't apply to any of the problem situations.

<sup>2</sup>If the LCA algorithm emits more than one commit hash ID, things get complicated; I don't cover that case here.

---

#### Using `git merge-file`

When Git does an automatic three-way merge on three file contents, it will identify sections that one "side" (e.g., ours / left-side / local) touched and the other side did not change, and will take the *change*.  Only where "our" and "their" changes actually overlap or abut will Git declare a merge conflict.

When Git doesn't identify the correct input files, though, its automated merging is useless.  For these cases, you simply have to extract the three inputs.  You can then feed the three files to [the `git merge-file` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file):

```
git merge-file ours base theirs
```

or:

```
git merge-file foo.LOCAL foo.BASE foo.REMOTE
```

(as `git mergetool` calls them).  Git will write its best effort at doing the same three-way merge as usual to the `ours` (or `foo.LOCAL`) file, treating the `base` and `theirs` files as the merge base and "remote".

The `git merge-file` command will use the same kind of conflict markers; to make it put the right text into the conflict markers, use the `-L` option.

#### Making the merge commit result

Once you have the correct file contents under the correct names, use `git add` (and `git rm` if necessary and appropriate) to tell Git that you've successfully combined the changes.  Then use `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to complete the merge.

If `git merge -X no-renames` tries to commit the merge because Git thinks it has done so successfully, even though it has not actually done so correctly, use the `--no-commit` option to prevent `git merge` from making a commit.

#### Cherry-pick

As noted above, cherry-pick is actually implemented using the merge engine.  Running:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-specifier>
```

runs the same change-combining code as `git merge` with one alteration: Git uses the *parent* of the specified commit as the merge base.

That is:

- the `--ours` commit is the `HEAD` commit as usual;
- the `--theirs` commit is the commit you specified as usual; but
- the merge base is the (single) parent of the specified commit.

Everything else works as for a regular merge, up until the merge is done.  Then instead of `git merge --continue`, you run `git cherry-pick --continue` (or, again, `git commit`) to have Git make a new commit.  Unlike with `git merge`, the new commit will be an ordinary (single-parent) commit.  As with `git merge`, if cherry-pick *thinks* it can do the cherry-pick on its own, but will get it wrong, you can use `--no-commit` to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Can you give an example to correctly merge a commit in my case?

Comment: @Silver: instead of `git merge foo`, use `git merge -X no-renames foo`.

Comment: just try it, git return a conflict. Git status give "deleted by us:"

Comment: Yes. That's because you deleted the file. "Rename" is "delete old file, create new file". You must resolve the conflict by choosing the correct name. (If you let Git see this *as* a rename, Git may think *it* can choose the correct name. If the result *is* the correct name, you're good, but if not, Git will go ahead and commit with the *wrong* name.)

Comment: if so, is there anyway to ask git to merge change of `code.cpp` to `src/code.cpp` because `no-renames` option will require manual code editing. And I do not understand and I have no idea how to "You must resolve the conflict by choosing the correct name". I assumpt you mean that I have to select either delete/modified `code.cpp` as suggest in `git-mergetool`, and it also mean that the change in `code.cpp` will not apply on `src/code.cpp`

Comment: Git says that you renamed a file *because* you deleted one file (`root/code.cpp`) and created two new files (`root/src/code.cpp` and `root/test/code.cpp`). You did in fact do that, whether we call that "delete one file, create two new files" or "rename one file, create one new file". When `git merge` goes to combine *that* work with *some other* work, Git won't be able to combine it correctly on its own. You must help Git out by choosing which file name(s) to keep and which work, if any, to combine in the files.

Comment: To do your own work-combining, consider using `git merge-file`, which implements the three-way merge given three input files. You'll need to extract all three input versions, from the merge base commit and the two branch-tip commits, though in general you'll have the two branch-tip versions handy anyway.

Comment: totally understood now. `git merge-file` is what I searching for. Please edit your answer with `git merge-file` part (possibly with an example) so that the question is perfectly answered. Thank alot